How to decrypt user data on Android / LineageOS via bootloader / TWRP / adb?
Phone: Google Pixel 3a XL
OS: Lineage
Goal: Retrieve personal data like photos
Problems: Forgot password pattern; user data encrypted
I forgot the password pattern to my Google Pixel 3a XL and want to get my photos out before doing a factory reset.
What I've done already:

Entered Recovery Mode
Enabled ADB and connected Phone to Laptop (Arch Linux (Manajaro))
Flashed TWRP image onto phone:
adb reboot boatloader, fastboot boot twrp.img
With TWRP UI on phone, I deleted a db file related to passwords in folder data/system/
Also accidentally deleted device_policies.xml, but created a new device_policies.xml and pushed it via adb
Booted OS/Lineage normally
Wasn't asked for a password anymore, but on display, it was saying "Smartphone is starting...", but nothing happened*
I was still able to swipe from top downwards, connected to WiFi, opened the settings, enabled USB debugging, and set a new password (this time 4 digits)
Repeated 1.-3., created backup with TWRP, did some other things with TWRP that I don't recall anymore (did not delete any more files though;)
Booted OS/Lineage normally again
Tried to decrypt the phone via settings, but the option seemed disabled
Repeated 1.-3.
Tried to decrypt data via TWRP - was asked for a password but the one I created before (see step 8) wasn't accepted
Tried to pull data via adb but no permission (I'm SU, rooted)
Now trying to boot OS normally fails - infinite Lineage logo animation

What I would like to achieve:
I only care about retrieving my personal data from the main user profile of that phone - i.e. the photos.
The problem is that neither can I pull data via adb nor decrypt the data via TWRP.
What options do I have left now? Please help - and keep in mind that I'm a complete noobie.
Could I somehow get the whole (relevant) partition out of the phone onto my laptop and then maybe try to decrypt the data using some brute force tool?
Or is there maybe an easier way to get the data?
*) Update: Don't know if the "Smartphone is starting..." message is related to the previously taken steps, since it only appeared after swiping to open the screen - which wasn't possible before due to the password protection which I bypassed by deleting that file (see 8.)

To my knowledge user data is encrypted by a key that can only be retrieved from gate keeper by providing the correct user pin/password/pattern.

You need to have your password or your data can't be decrypted by TWRP. The security chip uses your password to unlock encryption keys.

Any encryption worth its salt is designed to prevent access without the key. This is what keeps the bad guys (including rogue nation states) from accessing your personal data, which is why you’d want encryption in the first place. The downside is that, if you lose/forget the key, you’ll be locked out of your own data.
Since losing/forgetting the key is always a risk, some encryption systems provide recovery mechanisms – which basically means storing a copy of the key somewhere else, often in a different form than the original key.
To my knowledge, Android encryption is pretty solid, at least when the device is powered off, up to the point at which the encrypted partition is unlocked on boot. (Apparently Google Play services have some backdoor, but it requires the device to be running, have a network connection, and the partition to be unlocked.) So there is no backdoor if you’ve forgotten your key. I am also not aware of any key backup/recovery option on Android (Google tends to consider user devices no more than a cache for their cloud services, hence they aren’t paying much attention to data recovery from the device).
Unless you’ve backed up your data somewhere, your best bet is to try to remember what unlock pattern you used. Otherwise, I’m afraid you’re out of luck this time.
To prevent this from happening in the future, I recommend:

Use a password manager, which stores your passwords in encrypted form. Keepass is a widely used free and open source password manager; clones for different operating systems (which support the same database format) are also available. Keep the password database on a different device.
Back up your data regularly. Cloud backup might me the easiest to set up, but you’ll be entrusting your data to a cloud provider. If you don’t want that, you will need to back up your data to another device, e.g. your laptop. Either way, this will also keep you from losing your data if your device gets lost, stolen or damaged – mobile phones are at a particular risk here.


thanks for your answer! i already unlocked the screen (deleted data/system/locksettings.db and then created a new password). the problem i'm facing now is that the apps (including file manager, gallery, sms..) aren't mounting - i see "phone is starting..." on screen - see this new post

if i can fix this issue then i could simply send my data (i.e. photos) to myself via usb debugging or email or some messenger..

@vuelicious What you did already invalidates any further attempt to access your previous data.

@ChanganAuto how so?
